# Where should I place environment-dependent configurations for zsh?

Tags: zsh

I have a repository on github that consists of most of my dot files, including files like `.zshrc`.

When I need to move to a new development environment, I just need to pull my dot files from github and make sure they are in the correct places.

But sometimes the new environment is quite different from the old one, for example, I may need to move from MacOS to some distribution of Linux.

These differences may render my configurations incorrect, so I'm wondering if I can move all those environment-dependent configurations out of `.zshrc` and saved in some external files.

Answer (score 2):

You can load additional files in your `~/.zshrc` with `source FILENAME`.

I have the following in my `~/.zshrc` to do so for all files with extension `.zsh` in `~/.zshrc.d`

```
# load additional configuration
if [[ -d ~/.zshrc.d ]]; then
    for file in ~/.zshrc.d/*.zsh; do
        source "$file"
    done
    unset file
fi
```

You can then just place only the files you need for a specific environment in there.

You could even go a step farther and create a subdirectory for each environment and load only the one needed. For example based on the content of `$OSTYPE`:

```
if [[ -d ~/.zshrc.d/${OSTYPE} ]]; then
    for file in ~/.zshrc.d/${OSTYPE}/*.zsh; do
        source "$file"
    done
    unset file
fi
```